# Expand non-trivial function in Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I urgently need help on the following Fourier series expansion:

$f(x) = -1$ on $(-\pi, 0)$ and $f(x) = x$ on $(0, \pi)$.

I would like to find the general formula for the Fourier coefficients, but I have a big problem with that as the function is just so different from all the other ones I have encountered so far as it changes on its domain.

Comment: $\int_{-a}^{a} g(x)dx=\int_{-a}^{0} g(x)dx+\int_{0}^{a} g(x)dx$ should deal with your pproblem

Comment: Thanks! That should work.